# How to delete HTML text between html tags in PHP using SimpleHtmlDom

Tags: php, html-parsing

Using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ I know this could extract the html text:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext; 

?>
```

But how to delete all the text?

For example, if I have this input HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lore Ipsum</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.<br/>
            Aenean <em>commodo</em> ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to get this output with SimpleHtmlDom:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <p><br/></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In other words, I want to keep the structure of the document only.

Please help.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Please clarify the question. It's unclear what you mean by "HTML Text" and whether "html tags" refers to the actual `<html>` root node or means any html element.

Comment: I'm referring to the plaintext of the of the html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure how to do that with SimpleHtmlDom. From it's manual, I'd assume something like

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
foreach( $html->find('text') as $text) {
    $text->plaintext = '';
}
```

However, you can also use PHP's native DOM parser. It can do XPath queries and should in general be a good deal faster:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.google.com');
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query('//text()') as $textNode) {
    $textNode->parentNode->removeChild($textNode);
}
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Set `innertext` Property of HTML Element to the Empty String

Using simplehtmldom.php:

```
$my_html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/'); 
$my_html->innertext = "";
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SimpleHtmlDom, but that would remove the entire innerHTML of the root element, effectively making the page empty, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Gordon, the question was "But how to delete **all** the text?". If the asker only wants to delete some text, he/she will have to drill down to the relevant element.

Comment: But Elements are not Text. In a proper DOM implementation, these are different things. I've asked the OP to clarify his terminology. It's too vague and ambiguous right now.

Comment: @Gordon:I have try this, like u said, it effectively make page empty, but the plaintext on html file is still there.